# ordering attribute does not work?

Tags: android

Diging into Property Animation, introduced in Android Honeycomb, I found an example of an Animator Set. In Dev Guide, it is written that "The set element (AnimatorSet) exposes a single attribute, ordering. Set this attribute to together (default) to play all the animations in this set at once. Set this attribute to sequentially to play the animations in the order they are declared". So, I tryed this attribute 
`<set android:ordering="sequentially"></set>`, but I got an error, saying `"error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`". Why is it so? Does the `<set>` part must be inside sth else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

android:ordering does not seem to be in the API anymore.

Use the android:startOffset element to time your animations correctly, otherwise they will happen simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the android namespace before using it. This will give the parsing error you're seeing:

```
<set android:ordering="sequentially">
```

whereas this will compile and create a sequential AnimatorSet:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:ordering="sequentially">
```